# Confusion with react native docs about 'ScrollView'

Tags: react-native, scrollview

The doc is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)
When I was reading official docs and try to figure out how to properly use ScrollView, I was confused with the following words:

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to
>   work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded
>   container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of
>   a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged)
>   or make sure all parent views have bounded height. Forgetting to
>   transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which
>   the element inspector makes easy to debug.
>
> Doesn't yet support other contained responders from blocking this
>   scroll view from becoming the responder.

1. What is `a scroll interaction` and how `contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container` via it?
2. What does `make sure all parent views have bounded height` mean? The parent of the `<ScrollView`> tag? What if I'd like to have to responsive layout?
3. What does `transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack` mean? What errors will occur if I forget to do that?
4. `Doesn't yet support other contained responders from blocking this
   scroll view from becoming the responder`
   Does `blocking this scroll view` mean the scroll view is not able to scroll?
   `becoming` which responder?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

1. What is `a scroll interaction` and how `contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container` via it?

> All of that information boils down to scrollview does not have an initial height but it needs a height in order to know the boundaries of scrolling.

2. What does `make sure all parent views have bounded height` mean? The parent of the ? What if I'd like to have to responsive layout?

> You can set a hard numbered height to the scrollview, but it's not recommended because it doesn't account for different phone sizes. If you want a responsive layout...then do the recommended flexbox way.

3. What does `transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack` mean? What errors will occur if I forget to do that?

> The recommended option is to use `{flex: 1}`, but child flexbox layouts are height and width dependent, so if the parent doesn't have a height, the flexbox is also set to zero.

4. `Doesn't yet support other contained responders from blocking this scroll view from becoming the responder`. Does `blocking this scroll view` mean the scroll view is not able to scroll? `becoming` which responder?

> This means that scroll view cannot be stopped by any events inside itself. For example: if you had a horizontal scrollview inside of a vertical scrollview, the horizontal scrollview will not stop the vertical scrollview.

Comment: Hi Rey. Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me an example about the the 'recommended flexbox way' to set a appropriate scrollview with its contained views?